# How to write modal bootstrap 3.36 in 4 to include another files in the modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I implemented bs4, but on the modal I have a problem. In bs4 the code work but the data is not inserted. it's like a blank page.

In this case, the value of $cInfo->configuration_title, does'nt appear.

```
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-refresh="true"  href="configuration_popup.php?<?php echo 'gID='. $_GET['gID'] . '&cID=' . $Qconfiguration->valueInt('configuration_id'); ?>" data-target="#myModal_<?php echo $Qconfiguration->valueInt('configuration_id'); ?>"><?php echo HTML::image (DIR_WS_ICONS . 'edit.gif', ICON_EDIT) ?></a>
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal_<?php echo $Qconfiguration->valueInt('configuration_id'); ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-content"  style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo $cInfo->configuration_title; ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="te"></div>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing the content of that variable without putting it in the modal to make sure you aren't looking at the wrong problem?

Comment: yes, echo, var_dump, print_r

Comment: And what does that show? Empty variable?

Comment: yes, variable is empty on bs4 but not in bs3